# Why dealloc is not generated by default in UIViewController class?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

This is something I have been curious about:

If you create a new UIViewController subclass in Xcode, they stub in a few functions including ViewDidUnload. But there is no dealloc method.

Why wouldn't they stub that method into the class?

Comment: Normally its not there. Add it to your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own templates for Xcode.  If you want to add a `dealloc` method to your template, go for it.

Look in `~/Library/Application Support/Apple/Developer Tools/Templates/`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's a reasonable question - it would seem including it would make sense, given there's a high liklihood that it would be used.  But I suppose the only answer which is possible here, is that they decided not to (for whatever reason).  You can of course add it yourself - and in iOS5 it may be fairly redundant with ARC.